# walrus not configured on centos in eucalyptus

Tags: tcp, centos, cloud, eucalyptus

During configuration of a private eucalyptus cloud on centos6 the following error is coming:

Could not connect to server : connection refused 
Is the server running on host "local host " (::1) and accepting Tcp/Ip connection on port 8777 ?
Could not connect to server : connection refused 
Is the server running on host "local host " (127.0.0.1) and accepting Tcp/Ip connection on port 8777 ?

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The message is for a generic admin tool error that occurs when credentials are not configured in the environment. In this case the tools attempt to connect to the Eucalyptus database to discover credentials. The error means that the tools were not able to connect to the database, which could be due to an expected condition, such as there is no database on the host, or the eucalyptus-cloud service is not running.

You don't say how you were trying to configure Eucalyptus, what version you are using or what command you ran when you saw the error, so it is hard to provide a specific answer.

You may need to run the command on the cloud controller, you could attempt to [source credentials](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/4.1.0/index.html#shared/source_eucarc.html), and to [troubleshoot](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/4.1.0/index.html#admin-guide/ops_ts.html) further you may want to check the cloud-error.log or look for any faults in the *-fault.log's.